# How to count value greater then x and check time duration

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have dataframe with column 'time' and 'value' . i want to cut this dataframe in pieces. check if value greater than 400 for continuous time  cut data piece and then check if other data piece have value greater 400 and so on. after this check every piece time is continuous or not , if time is continuous then lenth of time.

input data

```
x=df[['time','value']]
print(x)
                      time              value
0       2019-06-01 00:00:02              407.0
1       2019-06-01 00:00:10              416.0
2       2019-06-01 00:00:18              415.0
3       2019-06-01 00:00:26              424.0
4       2019-06-01 00:00:34              450.0
5       2019-06-01 00:00:42              468.0
6       2019-06-01 00:00:50              482.0
7       2019-06-01 00:00:58              492.0
8       2019-06-01 00:01:06              459.0
9       2019-06-01 00:01:14              393.0
10      2019-06-01 00:01:22              333.0
11      2019-06-01 00:01:30              297.0
12      2019-06-01 00:01:38              450.0
13      2019-06-01 00:01:46              460.0
14      2019-06-01 00:01:54              455.0
```

desired output

```
print(piece_one)
                      time              value
0       2019-06-01 00:00:02              407.0
1       2019-06-01 00:00:10              416.0
2       2019-06-01 00:00:18              415.0
3       2019-06-01 00:00:26              424.0
4       2019-06-01 00:00:34              450.0
5       2019-06-01 00:00:42              468.0
6       2019-06-01 00:00:50              482.0
7       2019-06-01 00:00:58              492.0

print(piece_two)
                      time              value
12      2019-06-01 00:01:38              450.0
13      2019-06-01 00:01:46              460.0
14      2019-06-01 00:01:54              455.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create mask by compare by scalar `400` with [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) first, then compare by shifted values and [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) for unique groups values, filter out `False` values by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and pass to `groupby` for list of DataFrames:

```
m = df['value'].gt(400)
dfs = [d for _, d in df.groupby(m.ne(m.shift()).cumsum()[m])]
print (dfs)
[                  time  value
0  2019-06-01 00:00:02  407.0
1  2019-06-01 00:00:10  416.0
2  2019-06-01 00:00:18  415.0
3  2019-06-01 00:00:26  424.0
4  2019-06-01 00:00:34  450.0
5  2019-06-01 00:00:42  468.0
6  2019-06-01 00:00:50  482.0
7  2019-06-01 00:00:58  492.0
8  2019-06-01 00:01:06  459.0,                    time  value
12  2019-06-01 00:01:38  450.0
13  2019-06-01 00:01:46  460.0
14  2019-06-01 00:01:54  455.0]
```

---

```
print (dfs[0])
                  time  value
0  2019-06-01 00:00:02  407.0
1  2019-06-01 00:00:10  416.0
2  2019-06-01 00:00:18  415.0
3  2019-06-01 00:00:26  424.0
4  2019-06-01 00:00:34  450.0
5  2019-06-01 00:00:42  468.0
6  2019-06-01 00:00:50  482.0
7  2019-06-01 00:00:58  492.0
8  2019-06-01 00:01:06  459.0

print (dfs[1])
                   time  value
12  2019-06-01 00:01:38  450.0
13  2019-06-01 00:01:46  460.0
14  2019-06-01 00:01:54  455.0
```

EDIT: If need processing each group is possibble create new column `g` by groups, test difference and compare by `5 minutes` and then use [`Series.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.all.html) with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for get groups if all values are `True`s:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df['m1'] = df['value'].gt(400)

df['g'] = df['m1'].ne(df['m1'].shift()).cumsum()
df['d'] = df.groupby(df['m1'])['time'].diff()
df['m2'] = df['d'].lt(pd.Timedelta(5 * 60, unit='s')) | df['d'].isna()
df['m3'] = df['m2'].groupby(df['g']).transform('all')
print (df)
                  time  value     m1  g        d    m2    m3
0  2019-06-01 00:00:02  407.0   True  1      NaT  True  True
1  2019-06-01 00:00:10  416.0   True  1 00:00:08  True  True
2  2019-06-01 00:00:18  415.0   True  1 00:00:08  True  True
3  2019-06-01 00:00:26  424.0   True  1 00:00:08  True  True
4  2019-06-01 00:00:34  450.0   True  1 00:00:08  True  True
5  2019-06-01 00:00:42  468.0   True  1 00:00:08  True  True
6  2019-06-01 00:00:50  482.0   True  1 00:00:08  True  True
7  2019-06-01 00:00:58  492.0   True  1 00:00:08  True  True
8  2019-06-01 00:01:06  459.0   True  1 00:00:08  True  True
9  2019-06-01 00:01:14  393.0  False  2      NaT  True  True
10 2019-06-01 00:01:22  333.0  False  2 00:00:08  True  True
11 2019-06-01 00:01:30  297.0  False  2 00:00:08  True  True
12 2019-06-01 00:01:38  450.0   True  3 00:00:32  True  True
13 2019-06-01 00:01:46  460.0   True  3 00:00:08  True  True
14 2019-06-01 00:01:54  455.0   True  3 00:00:08  True  True
```

Filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[df['m1'] & df['m3']]
print (df1)
                  time  value    m1  g        d    m2    m3
0  2019-06-01 00:00:02  407.0  True  1      NaT  True  True
1  2019-06-01 00:00:10  416.0  True  1 00:00:08  True  True
2  2019-06-01 00:00:18  415.0  True  1 00:00:08  True  True
3  2019-06-01 00:00:26  424.0  True  1 00:00:08  True  True
4  2019-06-01 00:00:34  450.0  True  1 00:00:08  True  True
5  2019-06-01 00:00:42  468.0  True  1 00:00:08  True  True
6  2019-06-01 00:00:50  482.0  True  1 00:00:08  True  True
7  2019-06-01 00:00:58  492.0  True  1 00:00:08  True  True
8  2019-06-01 00:01:06  459.0  True  1 00:00:08  True  True
12 2019-06-01 00:01:38  450.0  True  3 00:00:32  True  True
13 2019-06-01 00:01:46  460.0  True  3 00:00:08  True  True
14 2019-06-01 00:01:54  455.0  True  3 00:00:08  True  True
```

And last aggregate [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) with 
[`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) for difference:

```
df2 = df1.groupby('g')['time'].agg(['first','last'])
df2['diff'] = df2['last'].sub(df2['first'])
print (df2)
                first                last     diff
g                                                 
1 2019-06-01 00:00:02 2019-06-01 00:01:06 00:01:04
3 2019-06-01 00:01:38 2019-06-01 00:01:54 00:00:16
```

Comment: pieces are in list , i want dataframe of each piece and check time is continuous or not , if time is continuous then what is the time length

Comment: @Edward - hmm, I check expected output and is it like you need. Do you need one dataframe with column for time difference? Can you explian more `check every piece time is continuous or not` ? It is 2 or more values? Or difference of times is not negative for each group?

Comment: dfs[0] have 8 rows first need to check time is continuous or not means check between two rows time jump should not more than 5 minutes . and time length means total time duration  between first row  and last row of piece , for example in dfs[0] time lenght is almost 1 minute